# What was the geopolitical status of Newfoundland prior to 1949?

Tags: british-empire, canada, political-geography

[Newfoundland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newfoundland_and_Labrador) "only" became part of Canada on March 31, 1949.
What was the geopolitical status of Newfoundland prior to its annexation to Canada (or however it fused with the rest of Canada, if "annexation" is the improper word here)?

I've read the Wiki page (linked above), yet I'm still a little confused with regards to the various different statuses N&L had before merging with Canada.  I gather it was a completely different autonomous region completely distinct and separate from Canada.

Can anyone point to political maps from prior to 1949?  How were Newfoundland and Labrador labeled? Er, at least to demarcate and differentiate them from the rest of Canada?

Comment: What do you want to know that isn't covered by the wikipedia page that you linked to?

Comment: @SteveBird: I was (and still am) confused by the various statuses Newfoundland and Labrador had prior to 1949.  Now, in my lifetime, there *was* Upper Volta (now Burkina Faso),  What was once Truk, Trust Territory of Pacific Islands is now Chuuk, Federated States of Micronesia.  When I was young, there was a single "Yugoslavia", now there are like 5 or 6 independent countries there.  The geopolitical landscape is changing, and I'm just curious how that area in the far eastern part of what I know as "Canada" looked like prior to 1949.  I think it's a legitimate question.

Comment: I still think this is well covered by the wikipedia articles on the [Newfoundland Colony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newfoundland_Colony), and the [Dominion of Newfoundland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominion_of_Newfoundland) which are both linked from the wikipedia page you linked to.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand what you're asking for. The wikipedia page outlines how Newfoundland was goverened and by whom. I don't want to put words in your mouth, but the best I can explain my confusion is that it seems to me as though you want a convenient box/category/taxonomy into which to classify Newfoundland.  I'm not sure that is how colonialism works.

Comment: From 1907 Newfoundland was a dominion. In 1933 it had its self government suspended but it remained a dominion. You could say that being a dominion without self government is pointless and not being a real dominion, but at least its formal "geopolitical status" was that of a dominion until it joined Canada.

Comment: Doesn't appear to still be a colony unlike say Greenland if that's what your asking.

Comment: While the articles linked to by @SteveBird are helpful, there's a lot of jargon in them.  I think there's a useful answer to this question to be had that would explain how British colonies were governed, what changed when Newfoundland became a "Crown colony", what changed when it became a "self-governing colony", what changed when it became a "dominion", and what its legal status was from 1933 to 1949.  Unfortunately, I don't really have the time or expertise to write such an answer...

Comment: I think there is a lot of potential in this question, especially because Newfoundland's fate was not 'known' prior to 1949. It was also an incredibly important base in WW2 and that might have been different had self-government remained in 1933. Dominions also would have aligned themselves with other countries dependent on their natural needs (and resources). In this case, this question might be *too broad* but it could be made suitable to this site in my opinion.